# Could a light dimmer be triggering my smoke detectors?

Tags: electrical, switch

I had LED recessed lights with a wall dimmer installed in one of our bedrooms by an electrician. Everything was working. Later in the day smoke detectors started to go off.

I called the electrician, he came back, wired the detector to the electric box to another breaker. Everything was fine for a few days, then they went off again just once a day with out any other lights on. When we have the lights on and shut the light dimmer off, the detectors stop.

Could the LED dimmer still be the problem?

Comment: Are you saying when the lights are at full brightness the detectors stop alarming?

Comment: how far apart are they

Comment: "When we have the lights on and shut the light dimmer off, the detectors stop" does this mean that turning off the lights causes the smoke detectors to stop beeping? Maybe the detectors are wired into one of the switches.

Answer (score 2):

Some dimmers cause electrical interference (radio frequency interference, RFI).

Check if it's heat or smoke causing the problem.

- If the issue starts **immediately** after the lamp is switched, perhaps only at a specific brightness setting, then it is likely RFI, not heat or smoke, causing the alarm.
- If the alarm(s) go on only after the lamp has been on for some time, this is a safety issue, due to overheating. *Have this fixed for safety,* and do not use that lamp until it has been fixed.

If it's RFI, then you have a few ways to try to fix the issue.

- Put ferrite filter chokes, like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZL2YQ19), over wires coming from the dimmer. They might also need to go near the lamp, as well.
- Add an inline noise filter, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FDYRQRY) to the dimmer circuit.
- Replace the dimmer with one that has internal RFI suppression, such as [this](https://a89b8e4143ca50438f09-7c1706ba3fabeeda794725d88e4f5e57.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/spec_sheets/files/000/061/054/original/leviton-6672-1lt-specs.pdf?1515163387).
- Replace the dimmer switch with a simple on/off toggle switch.

The examples above are just for reference, and might not be suitable in your locale.